# Is HCl in salt form reactive with metallized aluminium plastic film?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, combustion, reactivity, amino-acids

I’m in the process of packaging an amino acid that contains HCl in salt form. The mixture is 60% base and 40% HCl salt.

Will this react to metallized aluminium plastic?

Comment: The carboxyl group is more acidic than the ammonium one.

Answer (score 1):

There likely is a plastic (e.g., polyethylene) layer underneath the aluminum, to seal to the plastic bottle.

Polythene is resistant to $\ce{HCl}$, though somewhat porous. You can specify a thicker layer, as from [this supplier](https://www.actionpackenterprises.com/aluminium-seal-foils.html): "20 mic./ 25mic. / 30 mic. / 40 mic.,20 mic./ 25mic. / 30 mic. / 40 mic.". **N.B.** Check with supplier whether thickness applies to aluminum, to polythene, or both.